# Does GrabCut Segmentation depend on the size of the image?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have been thinking about this for quite some time, but never really performed detailed analysis on this. Does the foreground segmentation using [GrabCut](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67890/paper_siggraph04.pdf)[1] algorithm depend on the size of the input image? Intuitively, it appears to me that since grabcut is based on color models, color distributions should not change as the size of the image changes, but [aliasing] artifacts in smaller images might play a role.

Any thoughts or existing experiments on the dependence of size of the image on image segmentation using grabcut would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

[1] C. Rother, V. Kolmogorov, and A. Blake, GrabCut: Interactive foreground extraction using iterated graph cuts, ACM Trans. Graph., vol. 23, pp. 309–314, 2004.

Answer (score 9):

Size matters.

The objective function of GrabCut balances two terms:

1. The unary term that measures the per-pixel fit to the foreground/background color model.
2. The smoothness term (pair-wise term) that measures the "complexity" of the segmentation boundary.

The first term (unary) scales with the **area** of the foreground while the second (smoothness) scales with the **perimeter** of the foreground.
So, if you scale your image by a x2 factor you increase the area by x4 while the perimeter scales only roughly by a x2 factor.

Therefore, if you tuned (or learned) the parameters of the energy function for a specific image size / scale, these parameters may not work for you in different image sizes.

PS
Did you know that Office 2010 "foreground selection tool" is based on GrabCut algorithm?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a PDF of the [GrabCut paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67890/paper_siggraph04.pdf), courtesy of Microsoft Research.

The two main effects of image size will be run time and the scale of details in the image which may be considered significant. Of these two, run time is the one which will bite you with GrabCut - graph cutting methods are already rather slow, and GrabCut uses them iteratively.

It's very common to start by downsampling the image to a smaller resolution, often in combination with a low-pass filter (i.e. you sample the source image with a Gaussian kernel). This significantly reduces the *n* which the algorithm runs over while reducing the effect of small details and noise on the result.

You can also use masking to restrict processing to only specific portions of the image. You're already getting some of this in GrabCut as the initial "grab" or selection stage, and again later during the brush-based refinement stage. This stage also gives you some implicit information about scale, i.e. the feature of interest is probably filling most of the selection region.

Recommendation:

Display the image at whatever scale is convenient and downsample the selected region to roughly the n = 100k to 200k range per their example. If you need to improve the result quality, use the result of the initial stage as the starting point for a following iteration at higher resolution.